# Print to remote office printer without VPN/WAN link

Tags: printing, network-printer, print-server

We currently have roughly 20 remote offices who are connected to our main site using consumer grade broadband and a VPN tunnel. The majority of these offices have at least 2 printers. Remote users log onto remote desktop servers at our main site using thin clients, and their printers are installed on those servers.

We will soon be deploying a remote desktop farm and remote desktop gateway, meaning that a VPN will no longer be required to log into the servers at our main site. Currently the only thing I can think of that will be a roadblock, is printing.

One possible workaround would be to install the printers on their thin clients, and then have them carried over to the server farm as a session printer. This would work of course, but is clunky, difficult to manage remotely, and possibly confusing for users (when they see many copies of the same printer name from different sessions).

If we were to have a print server at our main site, what kind of options do we have to connect to those printers remotely? Most printers are HPs, but most offices also have a Konica Minolta scanner. If you had a couple of HP printers, i'm guessing port forwarding isn't going to work as the printers would probably be set to use the same port number.